# Answer flagged as "not an answer", regarded helpful, then minor-edited shortly afterwards

Tags: discussion, flags

To a question asking for a html file with all HTML5 elements present (admittedly, skirting round the edges of external-recommendation-closability but highly regarded (+10)) I flagged the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26075617) as "not an answer" and it was marked "helpful":

> Use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+v for !DOCTYPE, a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, area, article, aside, audio, b, base, basefont, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, button, canvas, ... [cut by me for brevity]

But shortly afterwards a user edited the answer to become:

> Use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> for !DOCTYPE, a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, area, article, aside, audio, b, base, basefont, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, button, canvas, ...

Why would an accepted flagged answer not be deleted and then be allowed to edit in such a way that it is not improved in any meaningful way?

Comment: Actually, that question should be flagged as *off-topic*. It is asking for an external resource.

Comment: Wow, the link color needs to be changed. I saw your edit @MartijnPieters and though "eh? nothing was changed"!

Comment: And your NAA flag should have been declined; it was only marked as helpful because someone edited the post. See [When to flag an answer as "it is not an answer"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552)

Comment: Please do take the time to study the post I linked. It may have been a bad answer, but it was *still* an *attempt* at answering the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, thanks for the education. In my view, listing doctypes to "ctrl+c and ctrl+v" in no way answers the question which is asking for HTML, but clearly my interpretation of the flag's purpose was incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The flag got handled by users going through /review. You can see [review details](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6331085). The action of editing was what caused the flag to get validated as helpful.

I think I would have declined the flag though if it had come through to moderator review. It looks like a genuine attempt to answer the question to me, which means it is not NAA.